# Is executeScript Immune from NoScript or Javascript Off Cases?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is executeScript method immune from the extensions like NoScript that prevents JS execution? Also does executeScript run if javascript is turned off in browser settings?

Comment: executeScript runs content scripts, not page scripts, so it's exempt from those cases.

Comment: Thanks. Add as an answer so that I accept it please.